# adding a string followed by an int to an array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, string, nsmutablearray, int

I am very new to Objective-C with Cocoa, and I need help.

I have a for statement in which I loop i from 1 to 18, and I would like to add an object to an NSMutableArray in this loop. Right now I have:

```
chapterList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:18];
for (int i = 1; i<19; i++)
{
    [chapterList addObject:@"Chapter"+ i];
}
```

I would like it to add the objects, chapter 1, chapter 2, chapter 3... , chapter 18. I have no idea how to do this, or even if it is possible. Is there a better way? Please Help

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You mean you want strings that say `Chapter 1`, `Chapter 2` etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
[chapterList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chapter %d", i]];
```

In Objective-C/Cocoa you can't append to a string using the `+` operator.  You either have to use things like `stringWithFormat:` to build the complete string that you want, or things like `stringByAppendingString:` to append data to an existing string.  The [NSString reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) might be a useful place to start.

Answer (score 3):

```
chapterList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:18];
for (int i = 1; i<19; i++)
{
    [chapterList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chapter %d",i]];
}
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting strings that merely say `Chapter 1`, `Chapter 2`, you can just do this:

```
chapterList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:18];
for (int i = 1; i<19; i++) {
    [chapterList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Chapter %d",i]];
}
```

And don't forget to release the array when you're done, as you're calling `alloc` on it.